# How can I discover new commands using M-x (or similar command) semantically?

Tags: search, help, apropos

Currently, I'm in Doom and I'm pressing <kbd>`M-x`</kbd> which does a nice fuzzy search for commands.

The problem with this is it has no synonym detection.  So if I'm trying to collapse something and type <kbd>`M-x collapse`</kbd>, `fold` does not come up.  Then I have to Google to find out the solution.  There is also <kbd>`C-h a`</kbd> for `apropos`, but that is a hassle.

When I'm searching for a command to do something, how can I do that in a semantic way?  Meaning that it searches by meaning instead of by text.  At least synonyms for the word I type will be included in the results.

This is related to the more general question of [semantic search in Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/71138/37556) and also to how to see [what keybindings are available when I'm in some minibuffer mode like Helm](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/77181/helm-see-options-for-opening-a-file) (please let me know if that is the correct terminology).

Comment: Please don't pose "best way" questions here. That encourages opinion-based answers and discussion. Ask instead "How can I...?". Thx. For best-way discussion, try a discussion site, such as Reddit.

Comment: Maybe you have a specific question, about how to find commands, including their synonyms...?

Comment: Thank you. I tried to make it more objective.

Comment: Thx...............

Answer (score 1):

`C-h a` is bound to command `apropos-command`. `C-h k C-h a` tells us:

> `C-h a` runs the command `apropos-command` (found in `global-map`), which is
> an autoloaded interactive Lisp function in ‘apropos.el’.
>
> It is bound to `C-h a`, `<f1> a`, `<help> a`, `<menu-bar> <help-menu> <search-documentation> <find-commands-by-name>`.
>
> `(apropos-command PATTERN &optional DO-ALL VAR-PREDICATE)`
>
> Show commands (interactively callable functions) that match `PATTERN`.
>
> `PATTERN` can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
> or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
> search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
> search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.
>
> With `C-u` prefix, or if `apropos-do-all` is non-`nil`, also show
> noninteractive functions.
>
> If `VAR-PREDICATE` is non-`nil`, show only variables, and only those that
> satisfy the predicate `VAR-PREDICATE`.
>
> When called from a Lisp program, a string `PATTERN` is used as a regexp,
> while a list of strings is used as a word list.

In addition, there are other apropos commands that help.  For example, `C-h d` is bound to `apropos-doc`:

> `apropos-documentation` is an autoloaded interactive byte-compiled Lisp
> function in ‘apropos.el’.
>
> It is bound to `C-h d`, `<f1> d`, `<help> d`, `<menu-bar> <help-menu> <search-documentation> <search-documentation-strings>`.
>
> `(apropos-documentation PATTERN &optional DO-ALL)`
>
> Show symbols whose documentation contains matches for `PATTERN`.
>
> `PATTERN` can be a word, a list of words (separated by spaces),
> or a regexp (using some regexp special characters).  If it is a word,
> search for matches for that word as a substring.  If it is a list of words,
> search for matches for any two (or more) of those words.
>
> Note that by default this command only searches in the file specified by
> `internal-doc-file-name`; i.e., the `etc/DOC` file.  With `C-u` prefix,
> or if `apropos-do-all` is non-`nil`, it searches all currently defined
> documentation strings.
>
> Returns list of symbols and documentation found.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then when you use `M-x` you can type get "apropos" matching for your input pattern in the minibuffer.  And you can use `C-M-RET` or `C-M-mouse-2` on any matches to see that command's description in `*Help*`.

There are also Icicles versions of the ordinary apropos commands, e.g., `icicle-doc` for `apropos-doc`.

See [A Propos d'Apropos](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_A_Propos_d%27Apropos).